# Internet Explorer 11 sending date in incorrect format to Laravel backend

Tags: php, laravel-5, internet-explorer-11

I have a form that contains the following input:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
    <label for="startdate">Start date</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="startdate" type="date" id="startdate">
</div>
```

I know the expected format for the backend to get a date value is yyyy-mm-dd (The [HTML5 date input specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110405/input.date.html) refers to the [RFC3339 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), which specifies a full-date format equal to: yyyy-mm-dd).

However it appears that Internet Explorer 11 sends the value in a different format because I get an error and the following message in my Laravel logs (using Laravel 5.8):

```
[2019-12-03 20:41:16] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '06/12/2019' for column 'startdate' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `absenses` (`motive`, `startdate`
at /var/www/zitthy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 22007): SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '06/12/2019' for column 'startdate'
at row 1 at /var/www/zitthy/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:123, PDOException(code: 22007): SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '06/12/2019' for column 'startdate'
at row 1 at /var/www/zitthy/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:121)
```

This works normally in Chrome and Firefox.

Any tips on how to fix this in IE11?

Thanks

Comment: Full support for `type="date"` inputs in IE came in IE12, so there may not be a full solution (at least not a non-hackish one)

Comment: when dealing with date the answer is usually "use momentjs"

Comment: Instead of a direct fix you can just hack it with a JS. Make a JS function which changes the value of the field to the desired format. And trigger it on onSubmit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="date">` is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility) by IE 11. It's a simple `<input>` in IE. The format of the value depends on the format you type in the `input`. So how do you handle the value in IE?

If you don't want to handle the value manually, you could use [polyfill](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html) to make `<input type="date">` compatible with IE. You could check my sample below, the value of date input in IE is the same format with it in Chrome after using the polyfill:

```js
webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {
  types: 'date'
});
webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');

function test() {
  var dateval = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
  console.log(dateval);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
  <label for="startdate">Start date</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="startdate" type="date" id="startdate">
  <input type="button" value="test" onclick="test()" />
</div>
```